# Rails 4 paperclip Background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, upload, paperclip

> **CURRENT LOGIC**

First, I think I have read all the articles on paperclip and I'm still stucked despite all the infos learned... So I can say taht your help is really really precious.

Secondly, I do not use delayed_paperclip, nor s3_direct_upload (but jquery directUpload).

I have users profile with 4 differents pictures : logo, avatar, worka, workb

> - Each format (logo, avatar, worka, workb) has 3 styles (:small, :thumb, :medium)
> - User can update its pictures => **so update action is concerned**
> - The 4 files fields are in a form with other classic fields (name, email, ...)
> - Upload is managed by jQuery DirectUpload + Paperclip

When user click the file field to add an image:

> - jQuery DirectUpload uploads the file into a temp directory on s3
> - jQuery callbacks with the url(key)
> - The url is assigned as :temp to an hidden field generated in javascript

When form submit button is pressed:

> - I assign to paperclip the url of the file uploaded with direct upload, with the help of `@user.logo.temp` which contains the url(key)
> - Paperclip generates all styles

```
<input type="hidden" name="user[logo_attributes][temp]" value="https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/e4b46d01-5d69-483b.jpg">
```

> **MY PROBLEM:** STYLES GENERATION BRINGS ME TO HEROKU IDLE and TIMEOUT #15 #12

.

> **ATTEMPTS:** I tried to isolate the upload process to put it in a background job

.

I can't figure out how to block paperclip styles generation at the first upload and generate them after in a background job

> - **before_post_process** block all post process, even in background job
> - I didn't use .reprocess! Since paperclip 4, **update is triggered and... infinite loop...**, so I use **.assign** and **.save** instead
>
>   - The file is correctly assigned from S3 hosted file, then processed by paperclip
>   - I'm not sure about the file from file field, if it is uploaded or not (no trace of that in the console, but since the form is submited, the file too, even if unused.

.

> **NEED:** STYLES BLOCKED THEN PROCESSING IN A BACKGROUND JOB

**My Logo Model**

```
class Logo < Document
  S3_TEMP_URL_FORMAT = %r{\/\/bucketname\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(?<path>temp\/.+\/(?<filename>.+))\z}.freeze

  has_attached_file :attachment,
  styles: { medium: "300x300#" },
  convert_options: { medium: "-quality 75 -strip" },
  default_url: ":parent_type/:class/:style/missing.png",
  path: "/documents/:parent_type/:id_partition/:class/:style/:basename.:extension"

  validates_attachment :attachment,
  content_type: { content_type: ["image/gif", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"] },
  size: { less_than: 1.megabyte }

  validates :temp, 
  # presence: true,
  format: { with: S3_TEMP_URL_FORMAT }

  before_save :set_attachment
  after_save :set_remote_url
  before_post_process :stop_process

  def stop_process
    false
  end

  def styles_process
    self.attachment.assign(attachment)
    self.save
  end

  def set_attachment
    # puts "BEGIN -- SET ATTACHMENT"
    tries ||= 5
    s3_temp_url_data = S3_TEMP_URL_FORMAT.match(self.temp)
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    s3_temp_head = s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']].objects[s3_temp_url_data[:path]].head
    self.attachment_file_name = s3_temp_url_data[:filename]
    self.attachment_file_size = s3_temp_head.content_length 
    self.attachment_content_type = s3_temp_head.content_type
    self.attachment_updated_at = s3_temp_head.last_modified 
  rescue AWS::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey => e
    tries -= 1
    if tries > 0
      sleep(3)
      retry
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def set_remote_url    
    s3_temp_url_data = S3_TEMP_URL_FORMAT.match(self.temp)
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    self.attachment = URI.parse(self.temp)
    self.save
    s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']].objects.with_prefix(s3_temp_url_data[:path]).delete_all
  end
end
```

**My Controller**

```
def update
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      # Here is the styles processing
      # This is where the Resque background job would go
      @user.logo.styles_process
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
end
```

**My Form**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), method: :put, html: { class: "form-horizontal directUpload", role: "form" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :logo do |l| %>
      <%=   l.file_field(:attachment, accept: 'image/gif,image/png,image/jpg,image/jpeg') %>
    <% end %>
    <input type="hidden" name="user[logo_attributes][temp]" value="https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/temp/e4b46d01-5d69-483b.jpg">
  <% end %>
```